# Building permits for solar in the USA

Tags: solar-power, law

I want to build a website that will estimate the cost of going solar.  Are building permits for installing solar in the united states done by County, City, or State? or does it vary?

Comment: They're controlled by the local council just like any other building permit. I think you need to expand your question and be more explicit about what you're asking. I guess that there are there are over 10,000 bodies that issue building permits (560 in Australia alone) and many of them can't be put into the categories you list.

Comment: Good point.  For now, my focus is on the United States.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., building permits are generally administered and controlled by the county. Contact your local county planning office to get more information on what their requirements are for solar.  If you are really lucky, you may even find you are eligible for a rebate of some sort for going "green."